# Getting session data in MVC actions with AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I use the [Authorize] attribute I can't get session data that I stored before. For example:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
   // do some stuff
   Session["Test"] = "Hi StackOverflow!";
}
```

And then I try to get it in another action, but with the [Authorize] attibute:

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult Test()
{
   // do some stuff
   if(Session["Test"] == null) 
   { 
      //do some more stuff
   }
}
```

`Session["Test"]` is always null. But if I remove the attribute it works. Can someone help me?

I'm instancing `Session["Test"]` in Session_Start.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you provided. Are you sure you are calling the `Index` action before the `Test` action? The `Authorize` attribute has nothing to do with session so I guess the problem is in another part of your code that you didn't provide.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure i'm calling the index action before, and it must be the Authorice attribute, because without it the code works,  thanks a lot.

Comment: I discovered that it is because i'm using the action to store the session from a flash control :(

Comment: @Pablo can you answer your own question if you've found the answer? It is easier for future reference and it improves your own accept-rate.